# Cannot submit new build to test on TestFlight

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7, testflight, application-loader

I am already testing a build on TestFlight, but today when I uploaded a new build (same app version), I cannot send it to test.

The bundle was uploaded successfully with `Application Loader` and appears in the list of builds on the `Activity` tab. Internal tester can install the new build without problems!

However, for external testers, when I choose `Add Build to Test` I can choose the new build, but on the final page (where I choose if I made any significant changes since previous submission) when I click submit, nothing happens.

It does show a spinning wheel for a second, but the window does not close and nothing happens. This happens no matter if I choose Yes or No to the Significant change question.

I use XCode 7.3.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today it worked, and I have two theories about the reason:

1) Yesterday I answered `No` to the Significant changes question first time I submitted. It could be that Apple detected that I did make significant changes and therefore blocked submission for 12 hours (answering Yes in the following attempts did not work either). Today I answered `Yes` in the first attempt, and then the build was accepted.

2) Testflight was simply down for several hours. However, if this was the case, I would expect others to report the same problem.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. Did you have to submit a new version before it would work, or just wait until that build worked?

Comment: I did not upload a new build. Just waited and then it worked.